# Doodle Draw App: lines drawn keep overlapping when (alpha < 1)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, drawrect, cgcontext

My Swift doodle app works, but when I change the alpha below '1.0', then I draw a line on the screen, the lines keeps overlapping. I created a custom Line class, drawView subclass of UIView. I've been messing around all day but can't seem to figure it out. See Below.

[image]

DrawView: UIView class

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    lastPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var newPoint = touch.locationInView(self)

    //from custom Line class: sets width and opacity as well
    lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint, color: drawColor, brushWidth: brushWidth, opacity: opacity))
    lastPoint = newPoint
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent){
    touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event) // adds point
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound)

    for line in lines {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, line.brushWidth)
        CGContextSetAlpha(context, line.opacity)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, line.color.CGColor)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, line.start.x, line.start.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
}
```

I don't know why it keeps overlapping. I some how need to track a the path then draw over it or somehow see if my CGPoints are the same while next to each other remove it or ignore it.

Is this possible using just one UIView?

Just now I tried using:

```
var touchesEnd: Bool = false //global variable
```

Then in touchesEnded:

```
touchesEnd = true
```

Finally in TouchesMoved:

```
 if touchesEnd == true {
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
 }
```

This is the most recent things i've tried but hasn't worked.

Comment: I also did ask it here but received no answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595927/ios-brush-that-doesnt-overlay-itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I draw lines with alpha < 1 in quartz 2d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407546/how-do-i-draw-lines-with-alpha-1-in-quartz-2d)

Comment: Did you ever solve your question. Possible duplicate link, is kinda old. I think there is a way to do this using only one UIView in swift. Can you undo that? Not to be a jerk but I want someone who has a lot more achievement points to tell me if it can/can't be done.

Comment: You won't get a better answer. Here is a pure Swift tutorial for that and as you can see It uses the same idea of merging image buffers. http://www.raywenderlich.com/87899/make-simple-drawing-app-uikit-swift

Comment: That's using two UIImageViews though. I'm using one UIView. I came across a demo inwhich who ever wrote the demo only uses one UIView. I don't have the link to download the demo but the name of it is "ACEDrawingViewDemo". I've been looking at his work but the past few days but it's extremely complicated. His demo is really fancy but with hundreds and hundreds of low stuff. His set up only has one UIView along with this buttons, sliders, and all.

Comment: Also, I've created a simple one using UIBezierPath which worked. I was able to change the Alpha (A > 1) as well as the color and it worked. I'm going Core Graphics with this doodle app currently.

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing me to that demo, it also answers my question. The idea is very simple. In the pen tool it just handles the CGPath which he extends every time the new point added and then just redraw the whole CGPath.

Comment: lol glad it solved yours. I started learning Swift after it came out so reading Obj-C is confusing. In the touchesBegan() why did he use a Bezierpath? which he adds it to 'pathArray' the in touchesMoved() he uses two previousPoints(1&2) followed by drawing a box and 'setNeedsDisplayInRect: drawBox) and not the default override? Then in his tools .m file he has a draw fuction but he has a rect fuction above it...I'm really confused. Can you explain in lyman's??